# How to force Apache 2.2 to send the full certificate chain?

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, reverse-proxy, mod-ssl

We are using Apache 2.2.25 with *mod_ssl* in the reverse proxy mode using *mod_proxy*. It has a server certificate we use for testing purposes, issued by GoDaddy. There are 3 certificates in the chain, `server cert -> GoDaddy intermediate CA -> GoDaddy Root CA`. The intermediate CA (*Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2*) is not always found in clients' list of trusted CA.

The SSL connection to the server works well for browsers (at least for some), but not for some other clients. We noticed that our server does not send the full certificate chain, by using the following command: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect SERVER_URL:443`, and indeed the command reports the error `Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)`

We use the `SSLCertificateFile` directive in each VirtualHost:

```
SSLCertificateFile certificate.crt
```

Where the certificate.crt file contains the private key and all the certificates in the chain.
We tried to split it into the following:

```
SSLCertificateFile server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile chain.crt
```

But this didn't change anything.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
The plot thickens - it seems to be some combination of the certificate and the server.
(testing is done with the [SSL Shopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) tool)

1. Go Daddy certificate (as above) on Apache 2.2 (RHEL) - **does not work**
2. same certificate, on IIS7 - **works**
3. customer's certificate (from Comodo) on Apache 2.2 RHEL - **works**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are on the right track.

```
SSLCertificateFile server.crt      >> Your public certificate
SSLCertificateKeyFile server.key   >> Your private key
SSLCertificateChainFile chain.crt  >> List of intermediate certificates;
                                 in your case, only one - GoDaddy intermediate CA
```

Check your server configuration with a tool like [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) to determine if you are sending the correct intermediate certificate.

Comment: thanks a lot, great tool! We are using `SSL Shopper` BTW. The problem actually looks even stranger - I'll add new info to the question, could you have a look and address? Thanks again

Comment: adding these directives in all Virtual Hosts solved the problem so I am accepting the answer

Comment: I created a shared `ssl/ssl.conf` and I include this in all our virtual host definitions in `sites-available` using `Include ssl/ssl.conf`.

Comment: This certainly helped.. Solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `SSLCACertificatePath` directive and put the original `.crt` files into the directory specified. However, you also have to create hash symlinks to them. This is done with the `c_rehash` tool, which is part of `openssl`. For example,

```
sudo c_rehash /etc/apache2/ssl/certs
```

However, note that there are two hash algorithms in use. The new one was introduced with `openssl` 1.0 and it's necessary to re-run `c_rehash` after upgrading `openssl` to 1.0 or later. This will create both old-style and new-style symlinks.

If you don't do this, `openssl` (and therefore `apache`) won't be able to find the intermediate certificates and so they won't be sent to the client. I spent a frustrating few hours debugging SSL errors after upgrading an Ubuntu server from Lucid to Precise, which had included an upgrade of `openssl` from 0.9.8 to 1.0.1. I searched but couldn't find any clues on the web about what was going wrong, so had to figure it out myself.

For the record, we weren't getting errors in the browser because it has a bigger set of roots and one of our intermediate certificates must have been in that set. The problem only showed up when using `openssl`-based command-line programs such as `wget`, `curl` and `openssl s_client`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This command solved my issue. I had a problem with certificate chain, most tools was saying me that certs chain is broken and an ads provider was unable to fetch my website because of this.
After running this command I solved my issue and now my certificate chain is valid. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has similar issues in the future:

In my case where one server didn't send a configured intermediate certificate (but other servers did) - it appeared to be an issue with line endings in the certificate file. Apparently Apache releases prior to 2019 can be rather picky - accepting only certificates with lines ending with new line (NL, char 10, Unix line endings), and silently ignoring certificate with lines ending with carriage return, new line (CR+NL, chars 13 and 10, Windows line endings), or carriage return only (CR, char 13, Mac OS <10).

My intermediate cert had the CR line endings (very odd in this day and age) - converting it to NL endings using a text editor fixed it up, and Apache now sends the intermediate certificate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had httpd 2.4 not sending the intermediate certificates defined with `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

It turned out the certificate files had wrong permission on the file system, and apache simply ignored them.
Correct permission mask is 400 :

```
[root@server ~]# ll /etc/httpd/conf/tls/certs/intermediate_chain.crt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1728 Mar  2 14:20 /etc/httpd/conf/tls/certs/intermediate_chain.crt 
#   ^  ^ wrong permissions

[root@server conf.d]# chmod 400 /etc/httpd/conf/tls/certs/intermediate_chain.crt 

[root@server ~]# ll /etc/httpd/conf/tls/certs/intermediate_chain.crt 
-rw------- 1 root root 1728 Mar  2 14:20 /etc/httpd/conf/tls/certs/intermediate_chain.crt 
#   ^  ^ correct permissions
```

Maybe this helps someone