# Let's Encrypt Certificate not working while using on JAVA API

Tags: java, spring, rest, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am developing a Java application that provides a REST API over HTTP.

For security reasons this communication should be switched to HTTPS.

I generate a trusted certificate from Let's Encrypt using certbot tool, this certificate seems to be working when I call my API from Chrome browser, but I get this exception when I use a Java 1.8.0_191 client based on Spring RestTemplate:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET 
request for "https://hostname/api/v1/event": 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
at 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
at 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669)
at 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:578)
at 
com.swingws.wiser.tasks.GetFrimwareVersionTask.main(GetFrimwareVersionTask.
java:80)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
at 
sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:
1639)
at 
sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:
1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at 
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(
AbstractD
elegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at 
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect
(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
at 
org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.
executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
at 
org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest
.executeIntern
al(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.
execute(AbstractClient    HttpRequest.java:53)
at 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:734)
... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building 
failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable 
to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
at 
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
at 
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:
324)
at 
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java
:229)
at 
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(
X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(
ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(
SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild( 
SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
... 23 more
```

Is there any way to make this working without adding this certificate to Java clients keystore ?

Comment: Did you add this certificate to java trust store?

Comment: No, since I have a trusted certificate, no need to add it to my java trusted store

Comment: Indeed version 191 should support letsencrypt certs.

Comment: Could you please run your client with -Djavax.net.debug=true and show output?

Comment: There is one idea, not really recommended for production code, but if you just want to test something you can always use `-Dtrust_all_cert=true`

Comment: @IgorKhvostenkov: `true` does not seem to be a valid option for `javax.net.debug`. It should be either `ssl` or `all`.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same issue and in our case the server that we contacted was misconfigured. It did not provide the full certificate chain. You can check that using [this tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

When the server is under your control, you should be able to configure this. When using Apache, you can configure this using SSLCertificateChainFile. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344893/how-to-force-apache-2-2-to-send-the-full-certificate-chain)